# Backup all pictures without iTunes

Tags: iphone, backup

My mother's iPhone has collected over 1000 family pictures from the camera, emails and WhatsApp. I am definitely *not* an Apple guy and I don't know where to even begin.

I'd like to save all the pictures on my computer and delete them off the phone. This will help me backup the pictures + create space on the iPhone.

What is the simplest way to do this without installing iTunes?

I do not have a MacBook or any laptop with Apple operating system on it. I do have an iPad though.

Comment: iTunes runs on a PC as well. Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the iPhone to a USB socket on your computer. The iPhone should prompt you to ask whether you trust the computer, click "Trust".

Depending how Windows (I'm assuming you are running Windows) is configured on your PC you might get an AutoPlay dialog that gives you a number of options including "Import pictures and videos".

If not then open "My Computer" (or "Computer" in more recent versions of Windows), where the iPhone should be listed as a device. If you right-click it there should be an option that says "Import pictures and videos".

You can find more detailed information here: http://www.wikihow.com/Transfer-Photos-from-an-iPhone-to-a-Computer